# Trouble running flutter apps on most iOS devices

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to be able to run flutter apps consistently on iOS. I have changed some settings on the iOS side a while ago, and now things are a bit wonky.  I can build the default Xcode hello world app on all the iOS devices I have tried, so as far as I know I have registered with Apple correctly.  I have not run into issues with the iOS simulator. I have not found a way to run any app on most devices.  If I create a brand new flutter app, or change the bundle id (explained later) the I am only able to run apps on one specific iPhone.  So I have two problems that I believe are related:

1. I am only able to run apps correctly on one specific device (iPhone 7 Plus). If I try a different device I get the following:

```
Signing iOS app for device deployment using developer identity: "Apple Development: roboteng@gmail.com (8SXLAQ739Z)"
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            6.2s
Installing and launching...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
No Provisioning Profile was found for your project's Bundle Identifier or your 
device. You can create a new Provisioning Profile for your project in Xcode for 
your team by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected. 
     - For Xcode 10, look under General > Signing > Team.
     - For Xcode 11 and newer, look under Signing & Capabilities > Team.
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again

It's also possible that a previously installed app with the same Bundle 
Identifier was signed with a different certificate.

For more information, please visit:
  https://flutter.dev/setup/#deploy-to-ios-devices

Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
2020-03-02 16:00:36.364 ios-deploy[84718:1415325] [ !! ] Error 0xe8008015: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found. AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication(0, device, url, options, install_callback, 0)
Could not install build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on 4f97b33c580c63029de5ef1caf08be5d781276db.
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Error launching application on Trevor’s iPad.
```

2. With the iPhone that does work, if I get a stub project from someone else (e.g. app brewery lessons) I need to manually change the bundle identifier from the default to `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = co.tws.quizzler;` within the file ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
   If I haven't changed this line I get:

````
Signing iOS app for device deployment using developer identity: "Apple Development: roboteng@gmail.com (8SXLAQ739Z)"
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            3.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2020-03-02 16:24:42.613 xcodebuild[88704:1485906]  DVTPortal: Service '<DVTPortalAppIDService: 0x7ff77316d6b0; action='addAppId'>' encountered an unexpected result code from the portal ('9401')
    2020-03-02 16:24:42.614 xcodebuild[88704:1485906]  DVTPortal: Error:
    Error Domain=DVTPortalServiceErrorDomain Code=9401 "An App ID with Identifier 'co.appbrewery.miCard' is not available. Please enter a different string." UserInfo={payload={
        creationTimestamp = "2020-03-02T23:24:42Z";
        httpCode = 200;
        protocolVersion = QH65B2;
        requestId = "27B41E22-9D92-48E4-8250-CFA4509E2156";
        requestUrl = "https://developerservices2.apple.com/services/QH65B2/ios/addAppId.action";
        responseId = "cdd5da76-1c76-4b8a-9298-fde35173de63";
        resultCode = 9401;
        resultString = "An App ID with Identifier 'co.appbrewery.miCard' is not available. Please enter a different string.";
        userLocale = "en_US";
        userString = "An App ID with Identifier 'co.appbrewery.miCard' is not available. Please enter a different string.";
    }, NSLocalizedDescription=An App ID with Identifier 'co.appbrewery.miCard' is not available. Please enter a different string.}
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    Code Signing Error: Failed to register bundle identifier. The app identifier "co.appbrewery.miCard" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.
    Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'co.appbrewery.miCard' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'co.appbrewery.miCard'.
    Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 13.2'
    Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 13.2'
    Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 13.2'

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on Trevor’s iPhone.```
````

Comment: So specifically, what I am am asking, is what do I need to change to be able to run all of my apps on all iOS devices?

Comment: " I have changed some settings on the iOS side a while ago, and now things are a bit wonky. " This is the important point here. What changes did you make? Can you rever those changes? This doesn't seem like it's a Flutter issue, it seems related to whichever changes you made.